# Parsing Hex Values in Java

Tags: java, colors, hex, shapes

I am new here and to clarify my question relates to a school assignment so I am looking for guidance rather than code. I'm working on a program in which a text file of information on simple primitives is read to produce shapes and text on an interface. The assignment can be found here: http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs165/.Spring18/assignments/P2/doc/

Unfortunately,  my output differs from the provided sample as the colors and fill for some of the shapes are off.

[image]

I have spent a long time trying to find the problem and the last thing I can think of is that since I have very little experience with hex values perhaps I am parsing them wrong. This seems like a stretch and I am open to any other input as to why my output differs.

I'll include below the code I have written for the Triangle class as well as the DrawProgram, DrawInterface, and UserInterface classes for reference, here is the content of simplePrimitives.txt:

```
TEXT,FF79E1,Programming is Fun,220,240,TimesRoman,15
TEXT,44B4D5,Java Rules!,240,270,TimesRoman,25
TEXT,0AFE47,Computer Science,230,300,TimesRoman,15

CIRCLE,FF7575,210,170,190,outline
CIRCLE,FFE920,180,150,40,filled
CIRCLE,6FFF64,390,150,40,filled
CIRCLE,CACAFF,420,180,40,filled
CIRCLE,BBDAFF,450,210,40,outline
CIRCLE,C06A45,450,250,40,filled
CIRCLE,4A9586,420,280,40,filled
CIRCLE,FF2626,390,310,40,filled
CIRCLE,F206FF,180,310,40,filled
CIRCLE,62FDCC,150,280,40,outline
CIRCLE,E8C6FF,120,250,40,filled
CIRCLE,800080,120,210,40,filled
CIRCLE,800080,150,180,40,filled

OVAL,62A9FF,10,50,80,30,outline
OVAL,F900F9,450,50,80,30,filled
OVAL,74FEF8,450,500,80,30,outline
OVAL,F7DE00,10,500,80,30,filled

SQUARE,99FD77,100,400,100,filled
SQUARE,FF800D,200,400,100,filled
SQUARE,FE8BF0,300,400,100,filled

TRIANGLE,FF4848,10,150,70,150,40,100,filled
TRIANGLE,6094DB,10,450,70,450,40,400,filled
TRIANGLE,4AE371,430,150,490,150,460,100,outline
TRIANGLE,DFDF00,430,450,490,450,460,400,filled

RECTANGLE,52FF20,120,20,300,100,filled
RECTANGLE,8C8CFF,125,25,290,90,filled
RECTANGLE,FFFF99,130,30,280,80,filled
RECTANGLE,C27E3A,135,35,270,70,filled
RECTANGLE,FF2DFF,140,40,250,60,filled
RECTANGLE,8ED6EA,145,45,240,50,filled
RECTANGLE,F70000,150,50,230,40,filled
RECTANGLE,0000Ce,155,55,220,30,filled
RECTANGLE,FFFFFF,160,60,210,20,filled
RECTANGLE,0000FF,165,65,200,10,filled
```

Triangle Class:

```
public class Triangle extends Primitive {

public int color;
public int x0,y0;
public int x1,y1;
public int x2,y2;
public int[] xPoints;
public int[] yPoints;
public boolean isFilled;

public void setColor(int color) {

    this.color = color;

}

public void setFilled(boolean isFilled) {

    this.isFilled = isFilled;

}

public Triangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
     this.xPoints = new int[3];
        this.yPoints = new int[3];
        this.xPoints[0] = x0;
        this.yPoints[0] = y0;
        this.xPoints[1] = x1;
        this.yPoints[1] = y1;
        this.xPoints[2] = x2;
        this.yPoints[2] = y2;
}

public void draw(UserInterface ui) {
      ui.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, isFilled);
        if (isFilled) {
            ui.fillColor(color);
        } else {
            ui.lineColor(color);
        }

}



}
```

DrawProgram:

```
// DrawProgram.java - Solution for drawing program
// Author: Chris Wilcox
// Date: 2/2/2017
// Class: CS165
// Email: wilcox@cs.colostate.edu

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DrawProgram {

public static UserInterface ui;

/**
 * Calls load, passing args[0] as the name of the text file containing graphics primitives.
 * Calls draw to draw the primitives.
 * @param args in this case, a valid filename for a Primitive file
 * @throws InterruptedException thrown when graphics program fails
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    // Drawing primitives
    ArrayList<Primitive> primitives;

    // Instantiate user interface
    ui = new UserInterface();

    // Close window
    ui.open();

    // Read primitives
    primitives = load(args[0]);

    // Draw primitives
    draw(primitives);

    // Wait for awhile (change if you want the drawing to be rendered for a
    // longer period of time.
    Thread.sleep(10000);

    // Close window
    ui.close();
}

/**
 * Read graphics primitives from file
 * @param filename the filename with primitive values
 * @return a list of primitives
 */
public static ArrayList<Primitive> load(String filename) {

    ArrayList<Primitive> primitives = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

            int x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,width,height,radius;

            // Read and parse line
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String[] fields = line.split(",");
            if (fields.length == 0) continue; // discard empty

            // Interpret primitives
            switch (fields[0]) {
                case "TEXT":
                    x0 = Integer.parseInt(fields[3]);
                    y0 = Integer.parseInt(fields[4]);
                    Text text = new Text(x0, y0 , fields[2]);
                    text.setColor(Integer.parseInt(fields[1], 16));
                    text.setFont(fields[5], Integer.parseInt(fields[6]));
                    primitives.add(text);
                    break;

                case "SQUARE":
                    x0 = Integer.parseInt(fields[2]);
                    y0 = Integer.parseInt(fields[3]);
                    Square square = new Square(x0, y0, Integer.parseInt(fields[4]));
                    square.setColor(Integer.parseInt(fields[1], 16));
                    square.setFilled(fields[5].equals("filled"));
                    primitives.add(square);
                    break;

                case "RECTANGLE":
                    x0 = Integer.parseInt(fields[2]);
                    y0 = Integer.parseInt(fields[3]);
                    width = Integer.parseInt(fields[4]);
                    height = Integer.parseInt(fields[5]);
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x0, y0, width, height);
                    rect.setColor(Integer.parseInt(fields[1], 16));
                    rect.setFilled(fields[6].equals("filled"));
                    primitives.add(rect);
                    break;

                    // YOUR CODE HERE - add triangle   
                case "TRIANGLE":
                    x0 =Integer.parseInt(fields[2]); //location on x-axis for the first point
                    y0 =Integer.parseInt(fields[3]); //location on y-axis for the first point
                    x1 =Integer.parseInt(fields[4]); //location on x-axis for the second point
                    y1 =Integer.parseInt(fields[5]); //location on y-axis for the second point
                    x2 =Integer.parseInt(fields[6]); //location on x-axis for the third point
                    y2 =Integer.parseInt(fields[7]); //location on y-axis for the third point

                    Triangle tri = new Triangle (x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2);

                    tri.setColor(Integer.parseInt(fields[1],16));
                    tri.setFilled(fields[8].equals("filled"));

                    primitives.add(tri);

                    break;


                // YOUR CODE HERE - add circle
                case "CIRCLE":
                    x0 = Integer.parseInt(fields[2]);  //location on the x-axis
                    y0 = Integer.parseInt(fields[3]); //location on the y-axis
                    radius = Integer.parseInt(fields[4]); // - size

                    Circle circ = new Circle (x0,y0,radius);

                    circ.setColor(Integer.parseInt(fields[1],16));
                    circ.setFilled((fields[5].equals("Filled")));

                    primitives.add(circ);

                    break;

                // YOUR CODE HERE - add oval
                case "OVAL":
                    x0 = Integer.parseInt(fields[2]);  //location on the x-axis
                    y0 = Integer.parseInt(fields[3]);  //location on the y-axis
                    width = Integer.parseInt(fields[4]);  //the width of the oval
                    height = Integer.parseInt(fields[5]);  //the height of the oval

                    Oval oval = new Oval (x0,y0,width,height);

                    oval.setColor(Integer.parseInt(fields[1],16));
                    oval.setFilled((fields[6].equals("Filled")));

                    primitives.add(oval);

                    break;
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot open file: " + filename);
    }
    return primitives;
}

/**
 * Draw graphics primitives in arraylist
 * @param primitives the list of Primitives
 */
public static void draw(ArrayList<Primitive> primitives) {

    for (Primitive primitive : primitives) {
        if (primitive instanceof Text)
            ((Text)primitive).draw(ui);
        else if (primitive instanceof Square)
            ((Square)primitive).draw(ui);
        else if (primitive instanceof Rectangle)
            ((Rectangle)primitive).draw(ui);

        // YOUR CODE HERE - add triangle
        else if (primitive instanceof Triangle)
            ((Triangle)primitive).draw(ui);

        // YOUR CODE HERE - add circle
        else if (primitive instanceof Circle)
            ((Circle)primitive).draw(ui);

        // YOUR CODE HERE - add oval
        else if (primitive instanceof Oval)
            ((Oval)primitive).draw(ui); }

    }
}
```

DrawInterface:

```
// DrawInterface.java - Interface class for drawing program
// Author: Chris Wilcox
// Date: 2/2/2017
// Class: CS165
// Email: wilcox@cs.colostate.edu

public interface DrawInterface {

//
// Graphics control
//

/**
 * Open window
 */
public abstract void open();

/**
 * Close window
 */
public abstract void close();

/**
 * Clear surface
 */
public abstract void clear();

//
// Graphics attributes
//
// Color selection
public abstract void lineColor(int color);
public abstract void fillColor(int color);
public abstract void textColor(int color);

/**
 * Font selection
 * @param fontName either Ariel or Times Roman
 * @param fontSize size of the font
 */
public abstract void setFont(String fontName, int fontSize);

//
// Graphics primitives

/**
 * Draw text
 * @param x the location on the x-axis
 * @param y the location on the y-axis
 * @param string the text that will be rendered
 */
public abstract void drawText(int x, int y, String string);

/**
 * Draw line
 * @param x0 location on the x-axis for the first point
 * @param y0 location on the y-axis for the first point
 * @param x1 location on the x-axis for the second point
 * @param y1 location on the y-axis for the second point
 */
public abstract void drawLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);

/**Trin
 * Draw rectangle (and square)
 * @param x location on the x-axis
 * @param y location on the y-axis
 * @param width the width of the rectangle
 * @param height the height of the rectangle
 * @param isFilled whether or not the rectangle is solid
 */
public abstract void drawRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean isFilled);

/**
 * Draw polygon (and triangle)
 * @param xPoints the coordinates for each point on the x-axis
 * @param yPoints the coordinates for each point on the y-axis
 * @param isFilled whether or not the polygon is solid
 */
public abstract void drawPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, boolean isFilled);

/**
 * Draw oval (and circle)
 * @param x location on the x-axis
 * @param y location on the y-axis
 * @param width the width of the oval or circle
 * @param height the height of the oval or circle
 * @param isFilled whether or not the shape is solid
 */
public abstract void drawOval(int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean isFilled);
}
```

UserInterface:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
* UserInterface.java - Graphics Code for drawing program
* Author: Chris Wilcox
* Date: 2/2/2017
* Class: CS165
 * Email: wilcox@cs.colostate.edu
 */
public class UserInterface extends JFrame implements DrawInterface {
// User interface variables
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel topPanel; // Text panel
private JPanel bottomPanel; // Drawing panel
private JLabel textLabel;
private Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 24);
private Color topColor = new Color(0x23A34A);
private Color bottomColor = new Color(0x6B8E23);
private BufferedImage surface; // Drawing surface
private Graphics2D gc; // Graphics context
private Color colorLine = Color.WHITE;
private Color colorFill = Color.WHITE;
private Color colorText = Color.WHITE;

private int gWidth; // Surface width
private int gHeight; // Surface height
private int numberPrimitives = 0; // Counts primitives

/**
 * noargs constructor for UserInterface
 */
public UserInterface() {

    // Platform customization
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setupTopPanel();    // Setup text area (top panel)
    setupBottomPanel(); // Setup drawing area (bottom panel)

    // Combine panels
    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Window setup
    setupWindow();

    // Initialize graphics
    initializeGraphics();
}


/**
 * Sets up the top panel for status area
 */
private void setupTopPanel() {

    textLabel = new JLabel("Number Primitives: " + numberPrimitives);
    textLabel.setFont(font);
    textLabel.setForeground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.add(textLabel);
    topPanel.setBackground(topColor);
}

/**
 * Sets up the bottom panel for drawing primitives
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private void setupBottomPanel() {

    // Setup for rendering
    bottomPanel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(surface, 0, 0, null);
        }
    };
    bottomPanel.setBackground(bottomColor);
}

/*
 * Sets up the window attributes
 */
private void setupWindow() {
    setSize(550, 650);
    setTitle("Drawing Application");
    setResizable(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Sets up the graphics context
 */
public void initializeGraphics() {

    gWidth = bottomPanel.getWidth();
    gHeight = bottomPanel.getHeight();
    surface = new BufferedImage(gWidth, gHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    gc = (Graphics2D) surface.getGraphics();
    gc.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    gc.setBackground(bottomColor);
    gc.clearRect(0, 0, gWidth, gHeight);
}

/**
 * Opens the window
 */
public void open() {
    setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Closes the window
 */
public void close() {
    setVisible(false);
    dispose();
}

/**
 * Clears the screen
 */
public void clear() {
    gc.setBackground(bottomColor);
    gc.clearRect(0, 0, gWidth, gHeight);
}

/**
 * Sets the line color
 * @param color the line color for the shapes
 */
public void lineColor(int color) {
    colorLine = new Color(color);
}

/**
 * Sets the fill color
 * @param color the fill color for the shapes
 */
public void fillColor(int color) {
    colorFill = new Color(color);
}

/**
 * Sets the text color
 * @param color hexadecimal color stored as an int
 */
public void textColor(int color) {
    colorText = new Color(color);
}

/**
 * Sets the font
 * @param fontName
 * @param fontSize
 */
public void setFont(String fontName, int fontSize) {
    gc.setFont(new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, fontSize));
}

/**
 * Draws text
 * @param x location on the x-axis
 * @param y location on the y-axis
 * @param string the text to render
 */
public void drawText(int x, int y, String string) {
    gc.setColor(colorText);
    gc.drawChars(string.toCharArray(), 0, string.length(), x, y);
    update();
}

/**
 * Draws a line
 * @param x0 location on the x-axis for the first point
 * @param y0 location on the y-axis for the first point
 * @param x1 location on the x-axis for the second point
 * @param y1 location on the y-axis for the second point
 */
public void drawLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
    gc.setColor(colorLine);
    gc.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
    update();
}

/**
 * Draws a rectangle
 * @param x location on the x-axis
 * @param y location on the y-axis
 * @param width width of the square or rectangle
 * @param height height of the square or rectangle
 * @param isFilled whether or not the shape is filled
 */
public void drawRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean isFilled) {
    if (isFilled) {
        gc.setColor(colorFill);
        gc.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
    else {
        gc.setColor(colorLine);
        gc.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
    update();
}

/**
 * Draws a polygon
 * @param xPoints the x coordinates for the polygon
 * @param yPoints the y coordinates for the polygon
 * @param isFilled whether or not the polygon is filled
 */
public void drawPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, boolean isFilled) {
    if (isFilled) {
        gc.setColor(colorFill);
        gc.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, xPoints.length);
    }
    else {
        gc.setColor(colorLine);
        gc.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, xPoints.length);
    }
    update();
}

/**
 * Draws an oval or circle
 * @param x location on the x-axis
 * @param y location on the y-axis
 * @param width the width of the oval or circle
 * @param height the height of the oval or circle
 * @param isFilled whether or not the shape is filled
 */
public void drawOval(int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean isFilled) {
    if (isFilled) {
        gc.setColor(colorFill);
        gc.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
    }
    else {
        gc.setColor(colorLine);
        gc.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
    }
    update();
}

/**
 * Update number of primitives
 */
private void update() {
    numberPrimitives++;
    textLabel.setText("Number Primitives: " + numberPrimitives);
    repaint();
}
}
```

I greatly appreciate any advice, thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colors issue is a logic error in the order of your `draw` method. If you look at the output, each shape draws using the color of the previously set color, instead of the correct one. You want to set your color before you draw the shape, so the code would look like this:

```
public void draw(UserInterface ui) {
    if (isFilled) {
        ui.fillColor(color);
    } else {
        ui.lineColor(color);
    }
    ui.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, isFilled);
}
```

Also you have a few typos in the `load` method of the `DrawProgram` class. In the cases of circle and oval, you have written `"Filled"` instead of the lower case `"filled"`, and you can tell since all the ovals and circles are outlines in your ouput.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just a few simple changes and my program is running beautifully, I really appreciate the explanation and the typos you pointed out I otherwise wouldn't have seen.

Comment: That's glad to hear! Please consider accepting my answer if it worked for you. :)